# Fake-Positive Bit-defender problem Gen:Variant.Tedy.304469

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks, bitdefender

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int compteAppels() {
    printf("hey");
return 0;
}
int main()
{
    int i, nbAppel;
    nbAppel = rand();
    for (i = 0; i < nbAppel; i++ ) {

        compteAppels();

    }

    return 0;
```

Bit-defender detect a threat when i compile this trivial script ( i'm on Code Blocks ) and put my file in quarantine , when i go in bitdef information about the threat it say it has been infected by "Gen:Variant.Tedy.304469"

I'm a student and beginner in C langage, I search on google "Gen:Variant.Tedy.304469" ( only 94 results lul ) i see people that may have the same issue than me but i just wanted to make sure, FYI the first time i got that issue was with a script that manipulate memory with malloc, i forgot once to deallocate so i thought it was the cause, but after i deallocate the issue was still here.

Comment: This is a common problem of modern anti-virus applications. The actual variant it detects isn't really relevant though. If the anti-virus support it, then you could add  the path to your development directory to a white-list, so it doesn't check there.

Comment: how can I do it ? I searched but i didnt find it ('-')